# Radio button select issue, while using Map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am having an list of array, which i am rendering the using the map function. Each object will have an radio button. Now, when i am clicking the radio button of a data, it shows, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined". I don't get, what i am doing wrong. Please check my code below.

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withStyles, Typography, Grid, Radio } from '@material-ui/core';

```
class EventSupervisor extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            lists: [
                {id: 1, proImg: require("../../../../../assets/images/man-avatar.jpg"), imgAlt: 'Profile Image', name: 'Sam', role: 'Teacher'},
                {id: 2, proImg: require("../../../../../assets/images/man-avatar.jpg"), imgAlt: 'Profile Image', name: 'Sam', role: 'Teacher'},
                {id: 3, proImg: require("../../../../../assets/images/man-avatar.jpg"), imgAlt: 'Profile Image', name: 'Sam', role: 'Teacher'}
            ],
            selectedValue: 1
        }
    }

    handleChange=(e)=>{
        this.setState({
            selectedValue: e.target.value
        })
    }
    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props
        return (
            <div className= {classes.supervisorWrapper}>

                <Grid container>
                    <Grid item xs='6'>
                        <Typography className={classes.selectContent}>Select Supervisor</Typography>
                        {/* <SupervisorList lists={this.state.lists} selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={this.handleChange}/> */}
                        {
                this.state.lists.map((list)=> { 
                    return (
                        <div className={classes.superWrapper} key={list.id}>
                            <img src={list.proImg} alt={list.imgAlt} />
                            <Typography className={classes.supervisorName}>{list.name}<span className={classes.supervisorRole}>{list.role}</span></Typography>
                            <Radio 
                                checked = {this.state.selectedValue === list.id}
                                onChange = {()=>this.handleChange(list.id)}
                                value = {this.state.selectedValue}
                                classes={{
                                    root: classes.radioRoot,
                                    checked: classes.rootChecked
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>    
                    )   
                })
            }
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs='6'>

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(EventSupervisor)
```

Comment: There is an issue in handleChange function. You are passing an ID(value) in handleChange not event object. posted an answer. Change handleChange method like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handleChange=(id)=>{
    this.setState({
        selectedValue: id
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function for handling the change is expected the event: `handleChange(e) --> selectedValue: e.target.value`, but in your onChange prop you're passing in the id: `onChange = {()=>this.handleChange(list.id)}`

Just change you `handleChange` function to take the id as an argument and use that to set the state: `handleChange(id) ---> selectedValue: id`

Answer (score 0):

```
<Radio
    ...
    onChange = {(e)=>this.handleChange(e)}
or
    onChange = {this.handleChange}
    ...
/>
```

e.target exists in click event.